# Does changing the openvpn server config affect already issued certificates?

Tags: openvpn, subnet

We've got an OpenVPN server running that is in use, with a number of static clients defined and certificates issued.

However, over time it's become apparent the the IP pool currently available isn't going to be sufficient.

We can change the config on the server to something like:

```
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.0.0
```

To open up the entire 10.8.*.* class B to fix this, however what I'm not sure of is if that would affect our existing ovpn certificates or static clients?

Comment: [This answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/284024/60293) shows some alternative options on how to expand the IP pool.

Answer (score 0):

**To your first question about certificates:**

Changing the subnet will not affect existing certificates.

**To your second question about the static clients:**

It depends on your setup.

> According openvpn manpage:
>
> ```
>  For example, --server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0 expands as follows:
>
>  mode server
>  tls-server
>  push "topology [topology]"
>
>  if dev tun AND (topology == net30 OR topology == p2p):
>    ifconfig 10.8.0.1 10.8.0.2
>    if !nopool:
>      ifconfig-pool 10.8.0.4 10.8.0.251
>    route 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
>    if client-to-client:
>      push "route 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0"
>    else if topology == net30:
>      push "route 10.8.0.1"
>
>  if dev tap OR (dev tun AND topology == subnet):
>    ifconfig 10.8.0.1 255.255.255.0
>    if !nopool:
>      ifconfig-pool 10.8.0.2 10.8.0.254 255.255.255.0
>    push "route-gateway 10.8.0.1"
>    if route-gateway unset:
>      route-gateway 10.8.0.2
> ```

If you change your subnet, the correct routes will be pushed to your clients automatically.

If you use `dev tun` with `topology subnet` and explicitly push `ifconfig` to your clients, you also have to update the subnet mask there, for example in a specific client-configuration-file of client with IP `10.8.0.2`:

```
ifconfig-push 10.8.0.2 255.255.0.0
```

In this scenario when a static IP is configured in the client-side configuration file, you have to update the subnet mask there:

```
ifconfig 10.8.0.2 255.255.0.0
```

**Some general remarks:**

An alternative would be to create a separate openvpn instance with a new configuration file serving an additional /24 subnet:

```
server 10.8.1.0 255.255.255.0
```

This could be better with regard to performance as explained [here](https://forums.openvpn.net/viewtopic.php?p=7923#p7923). Although the second instance will needs to listen on a **separate port** and if you need **subnet to subnet** connectivity, you also have to push the routes to the other vpn subnets.